# Location updates in thread

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to write an app which will put marker in place of current location, i have found this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

and i write this little piec of code to check in in thread

```
     Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(!running) {
                if(gpstracker.canGetLocation()) {
                    double lon = gpstracker.getLongitude();
                    double lat = gpstracker.getLatitude();
                    now = new LatLng(lat,lon);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            change(now);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    gpstracker.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

But location is never being changed, its always `0.0, 0.0` does location api changed much, so code from link does not work or maybe i'm calling it in wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but i don't know english .Hope i can help you.

```
 public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
```

lat = 0.0 and lon = 0.0 may be location is null-> location is lastknowLocation -> lastknowLocation can be null if gpshas never opened  before . So if you are testing code with emulator you can set location in Emulator Control to make it work . If you test code with device you just turn on gps and open map then open app test again.

Ah. We have new api location to use better you can read here : https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Thats true,  what u have said, but it works only for one time, i mean it get last known location but if i send new location using geo fix it does not uppdate

Comment: oh. your code you just get lat - lon but doesn't get LastknowGps again after 5s  . All you need is move  gpstracker = new GPStracker() into while loop with this location will be update .

Comment: I had to move it to runOnUiThread and it worked, i dont know how it can affect ui but now it works